# How to change the app name in OSX menubar in a pure-Python application bundle?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, bundle, py2app

I am trying to create a pure-Python application bundle for a wxPython app. I created the .app directory with the files described in Apple docs, with an Info.plist file etc. The only difference between a "normal" app and this bundle is that the entry point (CFBundleExecutable) is a script which starts with the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5
```

Everything works fine except that the application name in the OSX menubar is still "Python" although I have set the CFBundleName in Info.plist (I copied the result of py2app, actually). [The full Info.plist can be viewed here](https://github.com/gyim/stupidgit/blob/435a6a8d55a7c95ca174a3b769a27b2ef842f74d/setup/osx/Info.plist).

How can I change this? I have read everywhere that the menubar name is only determined by CFBundleName. How is it possible that the Python interpreter can change this in runtime?

**Note:** I was using py2app before, but the result was too large (>50 MB instead of the current 100KB) and it was not even portable between Leopard and Snow Leopard... so it  seems to be much easier to create a pure-Python app bundle "by hand" than transforming the output of py2app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Build Applet.app" that comes with the Python developer tools is actually a pure-Python app bundle. It does the following:

- a Python interpreter is placed (or linked) into the `MacOS/` directory
- the executable script (`Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo`) sets up some environment variables and calls `os.execve()` to this interpreter.

The executable script looks like this (it is assumed that the entry point of the program is in `Resources/main.py`):

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
import sys, os
execdir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
executable = os.path.join(execdir, "Python")
resdir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(execdir), "Resources")
libdir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(execdir), "Frameworks")
mainprogram = os.path.join(resdir, "main.py")

sys.argv.insert(1, mainprogram)
pypath = os.getenv("PYTHONPATH", "")
if pypath:
    pypath = ":" + pypath
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = resdir + pypath
os.environ["PYTHONEXECUTABLE"] = executable
os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = libdir
os.environ["DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH"] = libdir
os.execve(executable, sys.argv, os.environ)
```

Comment: Sorry, so what exactly is changed here?  I am having the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

Change a key called `LSHasLocalizedDisplayName` in `Info.plist` to `true`, as in:

```
<key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
<true/>
```

and then create a file in the executable bundle

```
foo.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
```

which has lines

```
CFBundleName="name in the menu bar";
CFBundleDisplayName="name in the Finder";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!... But no luck :( I have also tried to add the CFBundleLocalizations key with no success.

Comment: I noticed the missing semicolons (it gave a warning), so it was not a problem. Here's the result: http://tinyurl.com/2wcqe9p

Comment: For me the "name in the Finder" part worked, but not the "name in the menu bar" part, which is what I care about most.  Testing these solutions is especially frustrating because the Mac tends to cache previous versions of your app.  Thus "touch Foo.app" is a useful command before each test.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you create a soft link to the python executable and use that rather than the executable itself (inside your MyApp.app/Contents/MacOs/-script-), everything seems to work properly.  I personally use a "#! /bin/sh" script instead and just use the "exec" command.  (I you may still have to use wx.App.SetAppName(MyAppName).)  For example:

```
#! /bin/sh

export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/[myPythonCode]
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib
exec "/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/[SoftLinkToPythonExe]" "/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/myAppMain.py"
```